# How to filter an existing queryset by the month instead of day

Tags: python, django, django-views, chart.js, django-queryset

I have a queryset that displays the amount of followers for each day of the month.

[image]

Views:

```
context["brandtwitterFollowerCounts"] = (
    TwitterFollowerCount.objects.filter(
        twitter_account=self.object.twitter_account, followers__gt=0
    )
    .distinct("created__date")
    .order_by("created__date")
)
context["brandTwitterFollowCreated"] = [
    i.created.strftime("%d %m") for i in context["brandtwitterFollowerCounts"]
]
context["brandTwitterFollowers"] = [
    i.followers for i in context["brandtwitterFollowerCounts"]
```

Dataset:

```
var newDataObjectTwo = {
  labels: {{ brandTwitterFollowCreated|safe }},
  datasets: [{
      label: 'Daily',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'rgb(29, 161, 242)',
      data: {{ brandTwitterFollowers|safe }}
  }],
}
```

I would like to filter this by months instead now. So as there are currently 3 months (08, 09, 10), the graph should only show 3 data points. Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I am not sure what the best way to explain it is.

Comment: You can use `__year` and `__month`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#year.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This just displays all of the data within a specific month. It doesn't combine all the data for each month and then display 1 piece of data for each month that is tracked.

Comment: There's no build-in-option in ´chart.js´, you have to filter your data on your own and use these results as the new chart data.

Comment: Look at [`DateField` truncation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#datefield-truncation). Note it's not clear in your question what exactly should be shown for each month: the value on the 1st? Or the sum of all values? Or something else?